# Why is The Icon Preview gone once it is in iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud, icon

My songs that are anywhere in my Mac show the icon preview but once I move them to the iCloud Drive, they are gone. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure entirely, But I'd guess

- That optimize storage is deleting the files to save space and the file content is not enough to generate a preview.
- Preview options in Empty space in Finder > Right click > Show Preview Options > Show icon Preview is unchecked for iCloud.

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: I have it checked on the "Show Icon Preview". It still just shows me the default icon.

Answer (score 0):

try copying it back from icloud to your mac, if the "icon preview" comes back then its just icloud not cacheing to save space, i've had it happen before but i'm on an older imac